# Any idea what font is this?

Tags: font-identification

Trying to identify this font. None of the online font matchers can find it. Any idea what it is?

[image]

Reminds me of "circus" fonts, but I can't find any that matches exactly.

This is from an old Latvian fairytale book published in 1987 (when Latvia was part of the Soviet Union): https://nemaloknig.com/book-11187.html

Comment: Since it's a really old print it might not be a digital font, and possibly not even a font family, just hand drawn.

Comment: Search for "Circus Fonts"... I'd wager you'll find it.

Comment: @Scott I tried :( Quoting myself, _"Reminds me of "circus" fonts, but I can't find any that matches exactly."_

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed that. '87 is on the cusp of the digital fonts.. but I have no idea how "modern" Latvia was in 1987.. so it's hit or miss as to wether there's a digital version. Chances are the font would be Cyrillic though... So, uhm.., Cyrillic Circus font?? Sorry I can't help. The way the A's match, I doubt it's hand drawn. But it could have been press-on type.

Comment: My guess is, that you'll never find a digital version of this font. It doesn't look entirely hand-made since the A's look similar, but it does have an analogue quality which hints that it hasn't been digitally redesigned using Bézier curves. If you are lucky you might be able to find the font in a scanned version of a Soviet type catalog on archive.org like [this](https://archive.org/details/1923AmericanTypeFoundersSpecimenBookCatalogue/page/n327) American one from 1923. Remember that the font can be way older than the book.